# Finding Hudson Log Files

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, hudson-api

Does anyone know how to search a Hudson server for the incremental log files that are generated from running reoccurring JUnit tests?  The Hudson dash board will show the last twenty tests, but we are looking for a log file that holds a complete history of Hudson builds and the status of each build.

Answer (score 1):

The file structure on the Hudson master will look like this:

```
$HUDSON_HOME
     |
     ---- jobs
           |
           ---- [job name]
                     |
                     ---- builds
```

Your files should be in the  directory underneath that.  However, if you're only keeping the last 20 builds, you're unlikely to find any files from previous builds.

If you're building on a slave, you may also find the files you're looking for under workspace/[job name] in the slave home directory.

Comment: If you backup your server, you should have more success with checking your old backups.

Comment: We ended up using JUNIT tests scheduled by Hudson that outputted to log files that are indexed in Splunk.  This allowed us to keep a full log of the builds.